# Python return fatal error with try except when compiling in pyinstaller

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller, try-except

I coded this in my script to execute a script.
When the Tkinter window is closed it returns the error and closes all the windows, but when I compile this with pyinstaller it returns me a fatal error!

```
while True:
   script()
   try:
        root.update()
   except TclError:
        break
exit()
```

Can I fix it?

Comment: Please provide full traceback

Comment: If this will give an error with your py file, it will also give an error with your exe, fatal error just means a normal python error that would occur. Please fix the indentation of this code too

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same error, its because when the user closes the Tkinter window, and code is still be running and trying to update Tkinter vars or screen.

you can fix this by assigning as a close function for Tkinter Window and when the user clicks it you can stop python from executing.

```
def close():
    '''Close UI and Python while UI Closed'''
    root.withdraw()#Close Tkinter window
    os._exit(0)#Forecefully quit PY

root = Tk()
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", close) #Calling close,if user clicks window close.
```

Comment: But when I try to use the protocol module the program does the error

Comment: How? I execute it with cmd? Because in python or in compiling it doesn't display any error

Comment: Open cmd and go to folder and type script name and enter